# How would I rewrite this simple table without using table? Having 2 divs side by side and the left one being centered

Tags: css

I'm trying to improve my skills. It's extremely straightforward to do what I want with a table like so

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    table {
      width: 500px;
    }
  </style>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="t">Thing_____</td>
      <td class="p">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

However I thought it'd be easy to do without a table and got nowhere close with the text breaking. It looks like a car accident. I was wondering is there a straightforward way of doing this without a table? or should I use a table even tho this isn't really a table?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .box {
      width: 700px;
      columns: 2;
    }
    
    .t {
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    p {
      width: 500px
    }
  </style>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="t">Thing_____</div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do the same output in this case:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .box {
      width: 500px;
      display:flex;
    }
    
    .t {
       margin:auto 5px;
    }

  </style>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="t">Thing_____</div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    <div>
</body>

</html>
```